# Command prompt result in label. Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, output

I want to put the result(output) of shell command into the label. The command works, but the label shows "0", however, in command prompt, the result is shown correctly, but I need it to be showed in label. I am also doing this for ubuntu.

```
 myg1 = Button(root, text="Rodyti informacija", command=lambda: gauti())
    myg1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

 def gauti():
        imti = tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        info = subprocess.call("id '{imti}' ".format(imti=imti), shell=True)
        w = Label(root, text= info)
        w.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.call()` returns the exit code of the process that you created (in this case 0 for success). If you want the text output of the process, you should instead call [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).